# Android equivalent to iCloud Key/Value Storage

Tags: android, react-native, icloud

I would like to store simple settings for my React Native app in a way that the same user could access them on different devices, but I would like to avoid having a full user account management.

On iOS iCloud Key/Value Store will be perfect for this, but is there a similar feature on Android?

Comment: No, Android doesn’t provide such mechanism..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup
May be this will help

Comment: Yes I noticed the backup feature, but didn't really understand if that really is a backup feature or if it can be used as a synced settings store between devices with the same logged in user.

Comment: I'm not sure too.

Answer (score 2):

There is the exact same feature, except you get 5MB instead of iClouds 1 MB, take a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup :)

If your minSDK is above API level 23 consider Android Auto Backup https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

The key-value backup is supported by API 8 and above (for reference: Big Nerd Ranch suggestes a minSDK of API level 19 - KitKat, which covers over 96,5%* of Android Devices, as of late 2018).

*Source: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/